# JQuery running on different classes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, codeigniter

I am trying to count how many checkboxes the user checked so I could disable the other input so it will enter the database. How can I run on different elements `$(" . ")` using an array of different classes because I have a few groups of inputs in my form.

```
 <script>
                var countChecked = function() {
                var n = $( ".neutral:checked" ).length;
                alert( n + (n === 1 ? " is" : " are") + " checked!" );
                };
                countChecked();

                $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", countChecked );

   </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
// Count ALL checked boxes.
console.log($(":checked").length)

// Count checkboxes for a set of given classes.
console.log($(".one, .two, .three, .four").filter(":checked").length)

// Or given as array
let targets = [".one", ".two", ".three", ".four"];
console.log($(targets.join(",")).filter(":checked").length)

// or without the dot
targets = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
console.log($(targets.map(x => `.${x}`).join(",")).filter(":checked").length)

// or if you want to do something separately for each class
const handleCheckboxes = (cls) => {
  var n = $(`.${cls}:checked`).length;
  console.log(`${n} of class ${cls} ${n === 1 ? "is" : "are"} checked!`);

  // do even more stuff here
};
targets.forEach(handleCheckboxes);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="one" type="checkbox" checked>

<input class="two" type="checkbox" checked>
<input class="two" type="checkbox" checked>
<input class="two" type="checkbox" checked>

<input class="three" type="checkbox">
<input class="three" type="checkbox">

<input class="four" type="checkbox" checked>
<input class="four" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: I have a few inputs for each class and I need to return the number of the checked ones  for each class so I could remove the disable from the other input tags of the form for the same class.

Comment: So you want to do it separately for a list of classes?

Comment: yes, but I need to return the count var so I could use it in an if statement for the other inputs of this class

Comment: Check my suggestion.

Comment: I just need to return the number of checked checkboxes into a var in PHP tag so I could use it

Comment: You haven't mentioned php before. I cannot help you with that. Moreover I am still confused and others probably too, what you actually want. Please edit your question, explain your needs completely and show an example (at least in pseudo code) of what you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215960/discussion-between-victorias-secret-and-paul).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop through all classes

```
//Array
var array = ["class1", "class2", "class3", "class4", "class5"];
```

```
//Loop
array.forEach((className, classIndex) => {
  var n = $('.' + className + ':checked').length;
  var term = n === 1 ? "is" : "are";
  console.log(n + ' of ' + className + term + ' checked');
});
```